# How to save (Commit) a temporary table in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo

I tried the following:

```
Commit Table Query1 As "C:\Temp\XYZ.TAB" TYPE Query Interactive
```

It does not work.

Comment: This statement should create a query table that will rerun the query on the same table. It does however require that the initial query has been created using a SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Commit Table Query1 As "C:\Temp\Query1.TAB" TYPE NATIVE Interactive
```